# RedirectPermanent causes odd results in an ASP.NET MVC 3 application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, redirect

This is just strange. There could be other issues, but here's the deal. I'm making an application that simply gathers information and redirects to a URL with the info passed as parameters on the URL. I'm using the ASP.NET MVC 3 (.NET 4.0) framework and I've never had to redirect to a URL outside the application before.

My initial attempt, I did:

```
return RedirectPermanent("http://www.google.com?" + qrystring);
```

This redirected to google, but I didn't see the parameters. I work at it a bit and change the URL to one inside the application but I'll still be using the full URL and not the routing because I want to ensure the values get there. Now, when I debug the application locally and mouse over my breakpoints it says:

"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."

Also, no matter what I change the URL to in my call to "RedirectPermanent", it always loads the Google page.

I've cleared out the Temporary Internet file history & ensured the ASPNET user has access to the folder. I've also closed & reopened the solution. I've also tried changing "RedirectPermanent" to "Redirect", but that didn't fix it. Breakpoints worked fine in this application before hitting that RedirectPermanent statement the first time.

FYI: I'm running Windows XP and am using IIS Express (ASP.NET Development Server). I'm also running the application locally in debug mode as opposed to on a server machine.
Thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried a good old IISReset?

Comment: This is being developed locally so its using IISExpress I imagine. I'm not sure how to reset that, outside of clicking the icon that appears in the sys tray when I start my app and clicking the "Stop" button. I've done this process numerous times, though, and it still hasn't helped the issue.

Comment: How are you building the `qrystring` variable? What's inside it? Did you properly url encode all values? Using string concatenations for building an url instead of using a parser is usually a bad idea.

Comment: It was almost certainly poorly formed. I was doing simple "?" + "varname=" + "varvalue&"....

Comment: Have you checked if browser actually tries to hit your app or immediately goes to redirect Url (i.e. by using Fiddler)?

Comment: I have used Fiddler and I think it does immediately go to the redirect URL. How to fix that though...I guess I could change the action name, but that seems a stop gap.

Comment: Tried changing my action name and the default action in the Global.asax.cs. Fiddler reports that the redirect URL was hit immediately and my application was never loaded (at least, according to Fiddler). This is so odd. Not sure how to undo what ever's been toggled to make this happen.

Comment: Tried full reboot. Same issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was a rather simple thing in the end.

Chrome cached the RedirectPermanent url. Debug symbols are loaded until later in the application when other initialization is done. Visual Studio loaded my application and chrome seeing the url being used performed the redirect.

I cleared out my cache in chrome and, presto, it all works fine again.